# Problem with installation of QGIS 2.8 in Mac OS X 10.7

Tags: qgis, installation, mac, osx

I had followed the installation process of QGIS for installing in my Mac OS X 10.7 (http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis).

However, I had a problem in the moment when I open the Qgis, that could see in the next image.

[image: Problem Report for QGIS]

Comment: I tried to install QGIS 2.8.4-1